# How to define number of rows of GridView at runtime in code behind using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to develop such a program in which the GridView's rows should be decided at run time.

i.e. I have a table in database called dealer capacity.

Dealer_ID          Capacity
D0001                           5

Now when the Dealer D00001 is selected from combo box the number of rows in grid view should be 5. I want to use the template field also.

My code for GridView is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdlicence" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Version_id" GridLines="None" BorderStyle="Solid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true"     
        CssClass="mGrid table" 
        PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" 
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" >
             <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Version_name" ItemStyle-CssClass="uppercase" ItemStyle-Width="150px"   HeaderText="Version" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Version_id" Visible="false" HeaderText="Version" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                       <center><asp:TextBox ID="txtprice" CssClass="alignments TextStyle" MaxLength="5"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></center>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Licence Id">
                <ItemTemplate>
                       <center><asp:TextBox ID="txtlicenceid" CssClass="alignments uppercase"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></center>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>


              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Purchase Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                       <center><asp:TextBox ID="txtpurchasedate"  onfocus="showCalendarControl(this);"  CssClass="alignments TextStyle"   runat="server"></asp:TextBox></center>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>


              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Expiry Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                       <center><asp:TextBox ID="txtexpirydate"  onfocus="showCalendarControl(this);"  CssClass="alignments TextStyle"   runat="server"></asp:TextBox></center>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload File">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <center><asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server"  /></center> 
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>


           </Columns>

           </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You want to display 5 empty rows ?

Comment: No I want to display some fields as per defined in <ASP:GridView> Control in source file @Behroz

Comment: No, I meant that will there be any rows in the grid that will be fetched from the database ?

Comment: I am binding the Grid in code behind in Page_Load(). @Behroz

Comment: Ahan. So, in case of D0001 you have 5 records in database ?

Comment: No sir if the capacity field of D00001 contains 5 then i have to provide him maximum 5 files using FileUpload control. So now I have to display 5 rows in  Gridview containing file name, size and FileUpload Control in each row. @Behroz

Comment: Add all of this information in the Question, so that people can answer you correctly. Whatever Chamika Sandamal has suggested is correct.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir. I already tried that but does not work. @Behroz

Answer (score 1):

You need to define [PageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize.aspx) for your GridView and remember to set [AllowPaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowpaging.aspx) to true for the GridView

[GridView.PageSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize.aspx)

> Gets or sets the number of records to display on a page in a GridView
>   control.
>
> The default is 10.

You may see this article: [GridView Paging Sample in ASP.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/gridview-paging-sample-in-Asp-Net/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the linq [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) and pass the number as parameter.

---

Updated according to the comment, use following code.

```
grdlicence.DataSourse= ds.Take(5);
grdlicence.DataBind();
```

Comment: Don't know how to use Linq.. @Chamika Sanamal

Comment: just include `System.Linq` in the using section and use above code to data bind

Comment: can you give me code example please???

I am posting you the page_Load() that binds the data to GridView Control..

     `cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AMIR-PC\\MOHEMMAD;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");

        string query = "Select * from Employees where EmployeeID=1";
        cn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cn.Close();`
Thank you ... @Chamika Sandamal

Comment: where is the data binding part?